# wordpress theme issue the theme is not working properly with format

Tags: css, html, wordpress

My wordpress website does not hold any of the formatting (header 1, header 2, bold, etc.) I just want the pages to format normally and hold the format when I make changes.

How can i fix this issue in editor of theme.

Thanks

Comment: Put some more info about the problem...

Comment: When i post anything in the pages of my site the format goes wrong.

Comment: Assessment Theme       This is just a BLANK starter WordPress Theme template -- WordPress v2.9.1

Comment: Any link to show me?

Comment: I'll try my best to help you.

Comment: Okay go check your Home pages. Take a look the layout.

Comment: That link is your website right?

Comment: http://imgur.com/REdYtBf Ok there is a step to change your style.

Answer (score 0):

Okay to change your stylesheet layout login to Wp-admin dashboard

```
Appearance > Editor > Your Name Theme(style.css)
```

Let me know if this helpful. If it's please not state a reason and i will update it again. Regards

Comment: Assessment Theme: Stylesheet (style.css)
 its already like that

Comment: You can adjust it from there. But make sure comment it the previous style. Try and you will get the result that you wanted. Let me know your result.